# Axios HTTP DELETE request returns 415 error

Tags: reactjs, http, asp.net-core, axios

I'm building a React.js app with ASP.NET Core as backend following a tutorial course. I'm using Axios to handle HTTP requests, I tested the get, post, put requests working fine, but keep getting error during a del request. Here is the simplified function that produces the same error:

```
  const handleDeleteActivityTest = () => {
    Axios.delete('https://localhost:5001/api/activities/e2beb0eb-eaaa-49ee-92d8-daf472210456');
  }
```

And the request prints the following error messages in the console:

> DELETE https://localhost:5001/api/activities/e2beb0eb-eaaa-49ee-92d8-daf472210456 415 
>   (Unsupported Media Type)
>
> createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 415
>       at createError (createError.js:16)
>       at settle (settle.js:17)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61)

But I tested in Postman, and the delete request works just fine and returns a 200 OK response, and I can see in the database that the entry is deleted:

[Postman DELETE response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KONzm.png)

I would really appreciate if someone can educate me what's going on here. Thank you and stay safe & happy.

EDIT ----------------------------------

Here is the backend code that handles the HTTP request. It is divided into two parts-- 1.) controller that receives the HTTP request and 2.) MediatR class that handles it:

1.)

```
namespace API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ActivitiesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IMediator _mediator;

        public ActivitiesController(IMediator mediator)
        {
            _mediator = mediator;
        }

        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Unit>> Delete(Guid id, Delete.Command command)
        {
            command.Id = id;
            return await _mediator.Send(command);
        }
    }
}
```

2.)

```
namespace Application.Activities
{
    public class Delete
    {
        public class Command : IRequest
        {
            public Guid Id { get; set; }
        }

        public class Handler : IRequestHandler<Command>
        {
            private readonly DataContext _context;

            public Handler(DataContext context)
            {
                _context = context;
            }

            public async Task<Unit> Handle(Command request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                var activity = await _context.Activities.FindAsync(request.Id);

                if (activity == null)
                    throw new Exception("Could not find activity");

                _context.Remove(activity);



                var success = await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;

                if (success) return Unit.Value;

                throw new Exception("Problem saving changes");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I found that the HttpDelete method in the controller receives id as a Guid, but in the React app id is typed as string, so I changed the type to string in the controller and MediatR class, but same http error 415.

Comment: Until other experts check in, I suggest you to check and compare the request headers you send in your browser and in Postman.

Comment: Can you post the ASP .NET controller/action method? Does it define any body parameters? It looks like you are sending an empty json object in the body in Postman. While you can make it work, DELETE requests are not supposed to have body which can confuse Axios.

Comment: Yes, it turns out my controller requires a body with data and header. As a temporary solution I modified the Axios delete call to send also a body:
{ data: {foo: "bar"}, headers: {headers: "***"} }
I will find a way for the controller to not require a body for a delete request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Axios doesn't send a **content-type** on a delete call. It looks like ASP.net core wants a **content-type**.

As a workaround you could just add a body to the delete call then Axios will add a **content-type** and that should do the trick.

```
const handleDeleteActivityTest = () => {
    Axios.delete('https://localhost:5001/api/activities/e2beb0eb-eaaa-49ee-92d8-daf472210456', {
      data: {foo: 'bar'}
    });
  }
```

Comment: Yes, found out the controller requires a body and header for a DELETE request. After modifying the Axios delete call to send also a body and header, works like a charm, thank you!